# Scientific Writing: Acceptance of "one does"?

Tags: writing-style, science, academia

Essentially what the title says: Are formulations like "To determine the unknowns one employs the following conditions" acceptable for scientific writing? My professor insists that sentences like this are not only inappropriate for scientific writing but bad style in general. Would you agree? And can you recommend a good reference when it comes to appropriate *grammar* regarding scientific writing?

Comment: I believe it's usual to use the passive voice in scientific writing - "The compound was placed in the test tube".

Comment: Better asked on [writers.se]

Comment: I suppose *one* is rather old-style today. "To determine the unknowns **you/ we** employ the following conditions ..."

Comment: There are great differences of opinion regarding the grammar of scientific writing. But I don't see any reason to argue with your professor in this case – *"one"* is clunky here. If your professor allows *"we"*,  rephrase it as *"we determine the unknowns by using the following conditions."* If your professor insists on no personal pronouns, rephrase it as *"the unknowns can be determined by using the following conditions."* (I am assuming that you actually determine the unknowns using those conditions.)

Comment: ... continued from last comment. If you are actually describing the ***standard*** procedure, and your paper is about a new and better way to determine the unknowns, then I think *"one"* works here.

Answer (score -2):

I do agree with your professor. The wording of your example seems stilted and stodgy, to me.  It's not really a problem of grammar, but rather adopting a more journalistic style. You're not trying to impress readers with how well you write, but rather to communicate with them.  Make it casual, immediate, short and choppy, using examples.  How can we determine unknowns? Here's how to use conditions that the unknowns must satisfy ...

Do a web search for texts on expository prose.

Comment: A small note of caution: _yes_ the style quoted is somewhat stilted and stodgy, but _some_ types of scientific writing expect it either like this or in the passive voice as mentioned in Kate's comment -- a "causal, short and choppy" style could be frowned upon. You _may_ do better on the [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) site (but check the rules first: at a minimum you'd need to go into more detail about your field of study and the specific type of "scientific writing" involved).